# SSIS OLEDB Destination error

Tags: ssis-2008

I am getting below error when I am trying to transfer records from SQL table to Oracle table

[Connection manager "Oracle"] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDB_NOPROVIDER_64BIT_ERROR.  The requested OLE DB provider MSDAORA.1 is not registered -- perhaps no 64-bit provider is available.  Error code: 0x00000000.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Service Components"  Hresult: 0x80040154  Description: "Class not registered".

Answer (score 0):

This can be corrected by one of the following two, with the first being the most likely resolution:

1. Install the 64-bit Microsoft OLE DB provider for Oracle.
2. In your SSIS package in the Solution Explorer, right-click on the solution name and select Properties.  When the Properties page opens, select Debugging on the left side.  On the right side under Debug Options, change Run64BitRuntime to False.

If you are running your SSIS jobs from a dedicated server and step #1 resolves this issue, you'll need to duplicate this provider install there as well.

Hope this helps.